# Cloudinary uploader not working with large videos

Tags: cloudinary

I'm generating an input tag with Java to upload videos directly from the browser, with the Cloudinary API, which works fine with small videos, but it doesn't work with a 50 MB one.

This is the code generating the input tag:

```
String html = cloudinary.uploader().imageUploadTag("file", options, htmlOptions);

Map options = ObjectUtils.asMap("resource_type", "video");
    options.put("callback", "/cloudinary_cors.html");
    options.put("eager", eager);
    options.put("eager_async", true);
    options.put("tags", videoTags);
    options.put("use_filename", true);

Map htmlOptions = ObjectUtils.asMap();
    htmlOptions.put("id", "videoInput");
    htmlOptions.put("class", "upload");
```

That's an example of the input tag generated:

```
<input type="file" name="file" 
       data-url="https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/rentalwebs/video/upload" 
       data-form-data="{"eager":"c_scale,h_720,w_1280","signature":"xxxfb0c461dxxx",
       "api_key":"xxx1647231xxx","eager_async":true,
       "callback":"/cloudinary_cors.html","tags":"Demo Website,1,Villa Demo 2",
       "use_filename":true,"timestamp":"1548357724"}" 
       data-cloudinary-field="file" class="cloudinary-fileupload upload" id="videoInput">
```

And finally, those are the .js scripts attached to the page with the input tag:

```
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery.ui.widget.js}" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/load-image.all.min.js}" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js}" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js}" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery.fileupload.js}" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js}" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js}" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js}" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery.cloudinary.js}" type='text/javascript'></script>


$(document).ready(function() {
              if($.fn.cloudinary_fileupload !== undefined) {
                $("input.cloudinary-fileupload[type=file]").cloudinary_fileupload();
                }
            });
```

I may be missing something, which I've been unable to find. There is some more code, dealing with the uploading process and the result, but I guess the problem occurs before, among the code I have attached at this question.

Comment: Can you share what the error message is that you are receiving from Cloudinary?

Comment: At the browser side it doesn't give any error message, or at least I haven't found it. I have a code that gets a preview image from the video and after the image appears on the screen, nothing else happens. I've tested it without the preview image code, with the same result. I guess the uploading process, never begins with those large videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to add the parameter `chunk_size` to your options map in Java. This should pass the chunk_size to blueimp which the javascript cloudinary_fileupload is built on.

I would add a chunk size of 20 MB, e.g. `options.put("chunk_size", 20000000);`